# Is this a function composed of multiple functions, i.e a function of a function? and how to solve it! //multivariable analysis

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

So i am given the following: 
$f(x,y)=x^y$ 
$u(x,y)=x+lny$ 
$v(x,y)= x-lny$ 
and suppose that a new function defined as:
 $g(u,v)=f(x(u,v),y(u,v))$ 
and i am asked to find the partial derivative at a two points one of which is $∂g(3,3)/∂u$ 
i am more interested in the way of thinking and approaching the question rather than the solution. 
Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Are you familiar with [the chain rule for partial derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions)?

Comment: i am or at least i think so